# Apple Macbook Pro Mid 2014 - 15" - Random Shutdown

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, shutdown

I am facing a random shutdown on my Apple Macbook Pro Mid 2014 - 15" laptop. I am using Mojave and I already deleted this extension AppleThunderboltNHI.kext. Today after random shut down I get this error message. Someone please decode this and let me explain the real problem? Thank you.

```
Anonymous UUID:       DC8B603C-7543-6FC4-8DCA-4363311E5F46

Wed Apr  8 11:45:51 2020

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff7f91a4a9d7): "exfat_truncate: file size not changing?"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/exfat/exfat-90.200.1/kext/exfat_alloc.c:2354
Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff91fdc33790 : 0xffffff800e3ae6ed 
0xffffff91fdc337e0 : 0xffffff800e4ea185 
0xffffff91fdc33820 : 0xffffff800e4db8ba 
0xffffff91fdc33890 : 0xffffff800e35bb40 
0xffffff91fdc338b0 : 0xffffff800e3ae107 
0xffffff91fdc339d0 : 0xffffff800e3adf53 
0xffffff91fdc33a40 : 0xffffff7f91a4a9d7 
0xffffff91fdc33a80 : 0xffffff7f91a458d8 
0xffffff91fdc33ad0 : 0xffffff800e631b5b 
0xffffff91fdc33b50 : 0xffffff800e60ff83 
0xffffff91fdc33f40 : 0xffffff800e9ba5ed 
0xffffff91fdc33fa0 : 0xffffff800e35c306 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.filesystems.exfat(1.4)[D4976A61-781B-3A9B-8929-0B3232F59753]@0xffffff7f91a41000->0xffffff7f91a50fff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: DesktopServicesH

Mac OS version:
18G103

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Tue Aug 20 16:57:14 PDT 2019; root:xnu-4903.271.2~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: C41337A1-0EC3-3896-A954-A1F85E849D53
Kernel slide:     0x000000000e000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff800e200000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff800e100000
System model name: MacBookPro11,2 (Mac-3CBD00234E554E41)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 13639222289873
last loaded kext at 13430897821769: com.apple.filesystems.exfat 1.4 (addr 0xffffff7f91a41000, size 65536)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.filesystems.exfat 1.4
com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.10
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.fileutil  20.036.15
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.filesystems.ntfs  3.13
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.5
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.25.11
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.50.12
com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics  3.50.12
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   282.54
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   282.54
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    6.0.14d3
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.driver.AGDCBacklightControl   3.50.12
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics   12.1.0
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.12.12
com.apple.driver.eficheck   1
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul  12.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.50.12
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    212
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.5.9
com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface   6.8.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFIVRDriver    4.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   6.0.14d3
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  408.250.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBStorageCoexistentDriver    456.260.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 456.260.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   255
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  255
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 255
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleVirtIO    2.1.3
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.200.4
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 1.0
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  945.275.7
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  329.260.5
com.apple.private.KextAudit 1.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   201
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 760.6
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   740.2
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSkywalkFamily 1
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 282.54
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    528
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   530.51
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    404.14
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   255.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.50.12
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.AppleGPUWrangler  3.50.12
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.50.12
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 282.54
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    530.66
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 282.54
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 6.0.14d3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   6.0.14d3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  6.0.14d3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   6.0.14d3
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   4.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 263
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  315.6
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   206.5
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   900.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  301.270.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 493.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    456.260.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  145.200.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   408.250.3
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   408.250.3
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.kext.CoreTrust    1
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  47
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    740.2
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0

EOF
Model: MacBookPro11,2, BootROM 158.0.0.0.0, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.2 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.18f15
Graphics: kHW_IntelIrisProItem, Intel Iris Pro, spdisplays_builtin
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533641465238412D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533641465238412D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x134), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.61.2 AirPortDriverBrcmNIC-1305.8)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.14d3, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0256F, 251 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: My Passport 25E2
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: 2.4G Device
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to delete Apple .kexts to get your computer to work. In fact it may even be the cause.

What were you doing at the time? It looks like a problem while working with an exFAT disk. Do you have any disks formatted as exFAT attached to your Mac?
At the very least, you could update your OS to Mojave 10.14.6: you're on an earlier version of Mojave.

Comment: Yes, I have attached my WD-External 4TB formatted in exFAT at the time when random shutdowns occur. I deleted AppleThunderboltNHI.kext because before delete my system shutdown within 5 mins of a reboot. Any solution, please?

Comment: First thing would be to update to the latest version of Mojave. I have the 15" 2014 MBP, and the AppleThunderboltNHI.kext is installed, so you shouldn't need to remove it.

Comment: @benwiggy There's odd, very common issue where some macbooks randomly shutdown. Currently, there is no known reason it occurs, but disabling the AppleThunderboltNHI.ktext solves it.